# Is there a general way to remove substring which starts with a number and ends with a Capital Letter in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Hard to describe, but basically, I'm trying to find a ***general*** method which would make this:

```r
    [1]" On The Grill(1)95 E Kennedy BlvdLakewood, NJ 08701(732) 942-6555Restaurants I had a business dinner at this restaurant with 5 other people. Everyone was pleased with their appetizers and main courses. We’ll be back for sure…" 
    [2]" Sushi Now231 3rd StLakewood, NJ 08701(732) 719-2275RestaurantsSushi BarsWebsiteMenuOrder Online"
```

into this:

```r
    [1] "95 E Kennedy Blvd"
    [2] "231 3rd St"
```

Using R. I know it involves regular expressions, but I am not as fluent as I would like to be.

Thanks!

Comment: Whatever the method you expect is, what prevents it from matching `2275Restaurants` as well?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I guess there's a space with the address number

Answer (score 2):

Your expected output doesn't have a very solid logic but looking at your expected data, you can achieve what you are trying using this regex,

```
^.*?(\d{2,}.*?[a-z])[A-Z].*
```

and replace it with `\1` as group1 captures the text you wanted.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BDotFX/1)**

**[R Code Demo](https://rextester.com/TZMQE23859)**

```
sub("^.*?(\\d{2,}.*?[a-z])[A-Z].*", "\\1", "On The Grill(1)95 E Kennedy BlvdLakewood, NJ 08701(732) 942-6555Restaurants I had a business dinner at this restaurant with 5 other people. Everyone was pleased with their appetizers and main courses. We’ll be back for sure…")
sub("^.*?(\\d{2,}.*?[a-z])[A-Z].*", "\\1", "Sushi Now231 3rd StLakewood, NJ 08701(732) 719-2275RestaurantsSushi BarsWebsiteMenuOrder Online")
```

Prints like you expected,

```
[1] "95 E Kennedy Blvd"
[1] "231 3rd St"
```

**Edit:**
Ok, `\d{2,}` may be a little data dependent, so here we can use another logic, where I'll start my capture with one or more digits only `\d+` but following with one or more whitespace, and also since the match stops just before `Lakewood` hence use a positive look ahead too `(?=Lakewood)` in the regex and updated and better regex one can use is this,

```
^.*?(\d+\s+.*?)(?=Lakewood).*
```

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/BDotFX/5)**

Now, if you want, you can even use `str_match` to extract the text using regex `\d+\s+.*?(?=Lakewood)` using following lines of code,

```
library(stringr)

str_match("On The Grill(1)95 E Kennedy BlvdLakewood, NJ 08701(732) 942-6555Restaurants I had a business dinner at this restaurant with 5 other people. Everyone was pleased with their appetizers and main courses. We’ll be back for sure…", "\\d+\\s+.*?(?=Lakewood)")
str_match("Sushi Now231 3rd StLakewood, NJ 08701(732) 719-2275RestaurantsSushi BarsWebsiteMenuOrder Online", "\\d+\\s+.*?(?=Lakewood)")
```

Prints,

```
     [,1]               
[1,] "95 E Kennedy Blvd"
     [,1]        
[1,] "231 3rd St"
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the OP wants the number to be _at least_ two digits.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Why? Addresses (at least in my experience) do not typically begin with a single digit

Comment: @duckmayr Because that seems like the building number part of an address which, AFAIK, doesn't have to be at least two digits of length.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: As expected output doesn't want that `(1)`, hence I had to use `\d{2,}`. Otherwise suggest a logic to achieve that output and I shall use your logic.

Comment: I tried it with one. Is it possible to remove the bracketed number?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I think that's not a valid argument. What if you had two or more digits in the brackets. I would say the logic is unclear at this point.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: If you see, I indeed started with that point, that there is no solid logic behind what is to be achieved, but with OP's expected output, I had to tweak the regex accordingly. Let OP come back and spear some logic about it, although he himself feels it hard to articulate. And tweaking regex for the logic if OP specifies something is easy enough to incorporate.

Answer (score 1):

[Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102956/pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55956925/8386140) is great and very general. However, in case you find it helpful, here's an alternate method:

```
x <- c(" On The Grill(1)95 E Kennedy BlvdLakewood, NJ 08701(732) 942-6555Restaurants I had a business dinner at this restaurant with 5 other people. Everyone was pleased with their appetizers and main courses. We’ll be back for sure…",
       " Sushi Now231 3rd StLakewood, NJ 08701(732) 719-2275RestaurantsSushi BarsWebsiteMenuOrder Online")
street_types <- c("Blvd", "St")
address_pattern <- paste("\\d+ .+?", street_types, collapse = "|")
stringr::str_extract_all(string = x, pattern = address_pattern, simplify = TRUE)
#      [,1]               
# [1,] "95 E Kennedy Blvd"
# [2,] "231 3rd St"
```

This solves the problem of 1 digit address numbers and allows you to specify street types, which may help you prevent other types of false positives (though may impose some false negatives if you don't exhaustively specify the street types).

Comment: Seems like a good ad-hoc method! I will definitely try this out.